# why when I add objects on top a uiscrollview, the objects go down a little bit even when I set all four constrains to 0?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm working on a To-Do-List app. In this app, I have a button that opens a separate UIView so the user can add things to do. This separate UIView has a scrollView. This scrollView has multiple objects inside it. When I run the app, objects inside the scrollView are pushed down a little bit, even though I set all constraints for the first object to 0. When I run it, it looks like the top constraint is set to 20 or something.
Why objects inside the scrollView are pushed down by xcode? How do i fix it?

I'm using swift 3 and xcode 8.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: I provided the code below as a separate comment, and in my app there are two other classes, should add them here as well???

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this in the storyboard

1. Select the view Controller
2. GO to attributes inspector
3. Uncheck adjust scroll View insets